# Conditional scoped slot templates in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates

Can I not do something like this?

```html
<template v-if="options.columns">
  one thing...
</template>
<template v-else slot-scope="scope">
  something else. scope doesn't work here. :(
</template>
```

When I try to do this, `scope` becomes undefined. The moment I remove v-if, else and use `scope` it works as expected.

Comment: You should check if else condition in the inner scope of `slot-scope` ...

Comment: I got to try that out but it sounds a little messier and hacky?!

Comment: Why not just two v-if's ?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing with the exact same problem, what's worse, mine is failing silently - I didn't see any errors.

#### Solution #1 move if else condition to the inner scope of `<template>`

As David Japan pointed out, you can check if else condition in the inner scope of `slot-scope`:

```
<template slot-scope="scope">
  <span v-if="options.columns">one thing...</span>
  <span v-else>something else.</span>
</template>
```

#### Solution #2 use `v-slot` instead of `slot-scope`

```
<template v-slot="scope" v-if="options.columns">
  one thing...
</template>
<template v-slot="scope" v-else>
  something else.
</template>
```

However I don't know why `v-slot` fixes it, I searched both in the official documentation and online but no clues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a workaround:

Create 2 different SFC for each possible use case and do conditional rendering.

Vuetify example:

```
// App.vue
<div>
  <ListMD v-if="this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name === 'md'" />
  <ListXS v-if="this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name === 'xs'" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Vue.js component you cannot have more than one template tag.

Why not using 'is' property for dynamic component ?

```
<template>
   <div :is='my-component'></div>
</template>
```

So you can load a component dynamicaly.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: I am not trying to render two different components there. I get the idea but what I would really like to know is why does scope becomes undefined when paired with a code like this?